# Python Dataframe dinamicamente

Tags: python, pandas, for

Tenho dados com as seguintes colunas: "Data","Codproduto","Venda","Quantidade"
Preciso criar vários data frames no python, filtrando produto e selecionando as outras colunas e que ficasse salvo sempre com o nome do produto, por exemplo: dados_123, dados_324.
Preciso de algo desse tipo, usando pandas:

```
dados_123 = dados.loc[dados.Codproduto==123, ['Data','Venda','Quantidade']]
```

O problema é que tenho 50 Codproduto distintos e eu precisava fazer isto dinamicamente para ir filtrando cada Codproduto e ir salvando já com o sufixo do Codproduto.

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Bruno, boa noite! Existe alguma finalidade especifica para se criar várias variáveis? conte seu objetivo final, talvez exista uma opção mais interessante. Abraço!

Comment: Bom dia! Eu quero fazer um modelo de projeção de demanda utilizando o Prophet, porém para utilizar no mesmo, deve-se conter apenas duas variáveis (ds e y), data e venda, respectivamente. Eu gostaria de fazer previsão para todos os produtos, porém no prophet não achei uma função que me deixasse setar que deveria fazer um modelo por produto, por isso achei que separar em vários df seria melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que você possa criar um data frame 'temporário', fazer as previsões e salvar em um xlsx por exemplo:

```
for cod in dados['Codproduto'].unique():
    df_temp = dados[dados['Codproduto'].isin([cod])][['Data','Quantidade']]
    df_temp.columns = ['ds','y']
    m = Prophet(daily_seasonality=True)
    m.fit(df_temp)
    future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=10)
    forecast = m.predict(future)
    forecast.to_excel(f'dados_{cod}.xlsx')
```